# Problemas com roteadores node + express

Tags: node.js, express.js, método

Tenho uma sequencia de metódos (get, post, put, delete), no entanto o método put está equivocado e não sei como resolver.

este é o trecho do código:

```
router.route('/')
    .get((req, res) => res.status(200).send('Lista de Produtos'))
    .post((req, res) => res.status(201).send(req.body))
    .put(':id',(req, res, next) => {
        const id = req.params.id;
        res.status(201).send({
            id: id,
            item: req.body
        });
    })
    .delete((req, res) => res.send('Remove Produtos'))
```

E este é o erro:

> Error: Route.put() requires a callback function but got a [object String]

Preciso que na url eu encaminhe um id como por exemplo : http://localhost:3000/products/123

O id seria 123..

e a resposta seria 
{
   "id" : "123",
   "item": {
   }
}

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde Vitor,

O exemplo que utilizo para criar CRUD's em Node é esse aqui, https://www.codementor.io/olatundegaruba/nodejs-restful-apis-in-10-minutes-q0sgsfhbd

Sugiro que dê uma olhada em como ele faz o req.params direto e na function de callback que ele poem em caso de erro

```
 exports.update_a_task = function(req, res) {
     Task.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.taskId}, req.body, {new: true}, function(err, task) {
         if (err)
             res.send(err);
         res.json(task);
     });
 };
```

O Task.findOneAndUpdate vem dessa parte aqui

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Task = mongoose.model('Tasks');
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Entendi Rodrigo Melo, essa foi a solução que tinha bolado também, porém achei um pouco fraca pelo fato de precisar utilizar somente em um método o id, ai preciso adicionar toda linha de código extra.. Mas tudo bem, está rodando e funcionando!! gostei de umas utilidades do dono do post que indicou! vou dar uma lida com mais calma. Obrigado!!